# Can't navigate to a page through editing url (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

The url `localhost:4200/dashboard/391` loads the module DashboardModule.

`dashboard.routing.module.ts` has the following view:

```
{
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'upload/step_1',
                component: StepOneComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'upload/step_2',
                component: StepTwoComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'upload/step_3',
                component: StepThreeComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'upload/step_4',
                component: StepFourComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
}
```

**CURRENT BEHAVIOR**

There is a button on `DashboardComponent` that leads to `StepOneComponent`. When I press it, the url changes to `localhost:4200/dashboard/391/upload/step_1` and the `StepOneComponent` is loaded (as expected).

**QUESTION**

When I'm on `localhost:4200/dashboard/391` and adding `upload/step_1` to the url manually I still observe the `DashboardComponent`, not `StepOneComponent`.

What I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

Here is how I load my `DashboardModule`:

```
{
        path: '',
        component: MainPageComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                loadChildren: '...',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'dashboard/:dashboardId',
                loadChildren: '../dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
            },
         ...
```

Comment: remove pathmatch full in dashboard and child routes it works

Comment: Removed but nothing... The url changes but needed component - not

Comment: was the problem solved?